# integrating spring and wso2 identity server remote client

Tags: spring-boot, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to integrate spring and wso2 identity server remote client

but I am facing some dependency issues

My POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2.wso2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1.wso2v12</version>
</dependency>
```

While running I am getting below exception:

```
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths
            at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipIn
            at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
            at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
            at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
            at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
            at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
            at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
            at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.ServiceLoader.parseLine(Unknown Source)
            ... 52 common frames omitted
```

And while building thorugh maven I am getting below error:

> error reading repository \org\wso2\securev
>   ault\org.wso2.securevault\1.0.0-wso2v2\org.wso2.securevault-1.0.0-wso2v2

Comment: Could you share your repository configuration and disk space?